# Debugging Native API in java

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface

I am Using some APIs which are native libraries.Is there a way to debug them in eclipse?
When I try to debug them, those native APIs do not get loaded and the session terminates abruptly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this answer [View Native Code From Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162550/view-native-code-from-eclipse/2167018#2167018)