# how to import and edit C++ code in eclipse using ndk?

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

Scenario:
I have run and compiled an existing c++ code of cocos2d-x on android emulator using eclipse and NDK (CDT and Sequoyah are installed)(c++ code edited outside the eclipse). but, not able to edit c++ code or debug during runtime.

If I open a c++ (main.cpp) file, the project gets contaminated with errors.
main.cpp is a file having java as well as c++ code in it. and already included in my project.
(closing the project and then reopening it solves the errors for the time being)

Problems are:

1) how to open existing c++ files in a working android project?

2) how to tell eclipse that it's a mixed code/project of c++ as well as java. and not an error

thanks.

Comment: http://blog.plicatibu.com/how-to-debug-cocos2d-x-and-java-code-using-eclipse/

Comment: http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162550/view-native-code-from-eclipse/2167018#2167018

Comment: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/1520?r=1525#message-1525

Comment: http://blog.plicatibu.com/how-to-debug-cocos2d-x-and-java-code-using-eclipse/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to tell eclipse that it's a mixed project, while in C++ perspective, go to new->Convert to C/C++ project. It's a misnomer, it makes it a mixed project.

In order to let it find the included files, go to project preferences->C++ Generel->Paths and Symbols. There you can add the include folders for C/C++ (separately). The folders you need are

`{Android NDK install dir}/sources/cxx-stl/{the stl that you're using if you're using it}/include`

and

`{Android NDK install dir}/platforms/Android[yourAPIlevel]/arch-arm/usr/include/android`.

BTW. I was following some tutorial for this process, and they've also recommended going to C/C++ build, and doing the following:

- uncheck "Use default build command"
- change build command to ndk-build (we'll come back to that)
- remove "all" from the text field next to "Build(Incremental Build)"
- uncheck clean

This way, you can also build from eclipse. And it's really nice because that way you can also simply press "Run" and it will compile the C++ code, put the .dll (or .so) in the right place, install, and run. One little detail though. I think this is with newer versions of android-ndk that you have to say `make APP=yourappname` at the android-ndk installation root. So, that ndk-build in eclipse doesn't work. In order to trigger make in the right place, you can simply use `make -C PATHTOYOURNDKINSTALLATION APP=yourappname` as the build command in eclipse.

Comment: hi, thnx for the reply. i have done that but. it's still having errors

Comment: You have chosen to convert the right project, right? If it still says that, check your Indexer settings under C/C++ general. BTW in my answer I said {Android NDK install dir} but you should replace it, that's not a special syntax for eclipse. Finally, if you're on windows, you might want to change the directions of the slashes. Final finally, try not to have space in your C/C++ file paths.

Comment: @enobayram: are you getting code-assitence while programming in eclipse? i.e. Suppose you want to type cocos2d::CCSprite * _ship;. After writing coc and pressing Ctrl + Space are you getting code assist? I am not getting this feature I used to have this feature while programming in Java. What can be the problem? I have used all the above steps.

Comment: @25061987 yes, I'm getting it. When you're working on a regular C++ (CDT based) project in eclipse, you get code assist out of the box if your setup is without problems. That's because eclipse knows about the libraries and the header files that you use. In NDK however, the build is handled externally, so you need to tell eclipse which header files to index. In project preferences->C++ Generel->Paths and Symbols try telling eclipse where to find the header files for your libraries (Cocos2d in this case). You should get content assist then. Good luck

Comment: @enobayram: I have followed all the steps to make a combined Java and C++ project. In C++ Build I have provided **Build Command** as **bash ${workspace_loc:/MyTestProject}/build_native.sh NDK_DEBUG=1 V=1**. In **Paths and Symbols** I have added Includes under **Includes** section. I have also included path of my classes folder under **Source Location** section. I have googled a lot about this problem because if **Content assitence** isnt wrking thn its realy dificult to learn combined programming you know the help we get pressing **Ctrl + Space** is all lost its also not auto checking errors.

Comment: @enobayram: I am using this Eclipse Helios IDE since long time should I consider fresh installation and configurations?

Comment: @25061987 Don't you get ANY content assist at all? Does it auto-complete when you start typing #incl and press ctrl+space? How about syntax highlighting? BTW, do you have space characters along the paths? Did you write the paths as you OS likes it? I strongly recommend upgrading to Eclipse Juno, since CDT has improved significantly over the last few releases. I don't see why you're not getting content assist otherwise... If you upgrade to Juno, and if it still doesn't work, tell me, along with your OS and I'll give it a try under the same conditions.

Comment: @enobayram:No I am not getting any content assist for cocos2D-X library include **#include "cocos2d.h"**. But surprising yesterday when I needed to set path for **#include "SimpleAudioEngine.h"** in **Paths and Symbols** I set path for **CocosDenshion** include and Content Assist started working for this include only not for cocos2D-X though. I have checked and none my paths contain Spaces. And I was to try Eclipse Juno but somebody asked me not to configure this installation with Juno [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716052/android-cocos2dx-using-c-in-eclipse-helios).

Comment: @enobayram:This might help you solve my problem. Please check [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qmC8a.png). This is what I got after clicking **Right Click Project -> Index -> Search for Unresolved Index**. But I have added all includes check [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ujvMs.png). I think this is causing problem in Content Assist. What should I do in this case? Inclusion seems proper.

Comment: @25061987 I see that the direction of the slashes for your cocos2d include folders are opposite to the system include folders, did you experiment with that? I need to ask again whether you get any content assist at all, including for C++ syntax such as the "include" keyword, or for the system header files such as iostream.

Comment: @enobayram: I also noticed that opposite slashes and changed accordingly system but no success. I am getting code assist for C++ syntax such as "include" keyword. But I would be using Cocos2D-X and not getting its classes and methods' content assist. when I needed to set path for **#include "SimpleAudioEngine.h"** which is also another include for getting audio functioning of Cocos2D-X in Paths and Symbols I set path for CocosDenshion include and Content Assist started working for this include only not for cocos2D-X though.

Answer (score 3):

Most solution is provided by enobayram, however I cannot get content assistance like comment by @25061987 while programming in eclipse.

I think this is not good solution to get the assistance, though it works well.

1. go to project preferences->C++ Generel->Paths and Symbols -> source Location
2. select link folder
3. Link to folder in the file system.
4. Add "cocos2dx, cocosdenshion" folders of "your COCOS2DX_ROOT"

Or Try this way
http://jpsarda.tumblr.com/post/26000816688/integrate-cocos2d-x-c-into-an-android-application
he copied every sources...